# How do I correct error: Contained fields field is required in Commerce Index Filters

Tags: commerce, search

Commerce Kickstart 2. I noticed that unpublished Products were still visible to users who are not logged in or have editing permissions.

I saw this topic: https://www.drupal.org/node/1899326 which states that one must check the 'Exclude unpublished nodes' box as well as the 'Exclude unpublished products' box in the Filters tab of

/admin/config/search/search_api/index/product_display/workflow

...but when I click 'Save' I get the error:

Contained fields field is required

...five times.

What is causing this? How do I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you found the solution for this error, but here is what i did.

on the /admin/config/search/search_api/index/product_display/workflow, the aggragated field settings, remove the fields that you don't need or have "unchecked" on the fields tab.

Hope this helps

Karim

Comment: Honestly, it's been so long, I've forgotten. One of the -key- failings of this 'forum' is that there is no way to 'bump' a topic; so if one doesn't get a quick reply, the question just disappears. I see hundreds of orphans here. That said, I -think- I found that there was a patch to SOLR that fixed it through endless Googling. You gotta be a Google-Ninja if you wanna use Commerce.